# Jaxb - How to avoid "xsi:" at root element

Tags: java, xml, xsd, jaxb

Im using Java 7 and trying to create an xml from an xsd with jaxb.

I generated Java classes from [xsd](http://www.eiv-fobi.de/downloads/eiv-punktemeldung.xsd).

class1:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"vnr",
"meldungsart",
"teilnehmeranzahl",
"email",
"teilnehmer"
 })
@XmlRootElement(name = "Veranstaltung")
public class Veranstaltung {

@XmlElement(name = "VNR", required = true)
protected String vnr;
@XmlElement(name = "Meldungsart", required = true)
protected String meldungsart;
@XmlElement(name = "Teilnehmeranzahl")
protected int teilnehmeranzahl;
@XmlElement(name = "EMAIL")
protected String email;
@XmlElement(name = "Teilnehmer")
protected List<Teilnehmer> teilnehmer;
```

class 2

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"efn",
"punkteBasisJN",
"punkteZusatzLernkontrolleJN",
"punkteInteraktivitaetJN",
"punkteReferent"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "Teilnehmer")
public class Teilnehmer {

@XmlElement(name = "EFN", required = true)
protected String efn;
@XmlElement(name = "Punkte_Basis_JN", required = true)
protected String punkteBasisJN;
@XmlElement(name = "Punkte_Zusatz_Lernkontrolle_JN", required = true)
protected String punkteZusatzLernkontrolleJN;
@XmlElement(name = "Punkte_Interaktivitaet_JN", required = true)
protected String punkteInteraktivitaetJN;
@XmlElement(name = "Punkte_Referent")
protected int punkteReferent;
```

Now I create a xml with JAXB:

```
    JAXBElement<eiv.Veranstaltung> tmp = ObjectFactoryNew
            .createEvent(event);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext
            .newInstance(eiv.Veranstaltung.class);
    Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_ENCODING, "ISO-8859-15");
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty("jaxb.noNamespaceSchemaLocation",
            "eiv-punktemeldung.xsd");
    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.FALSE);

    jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
    jaxbMarshaller.marshal(tmp, System.out);
```

ObjectFactory.java

```
@XmlRegistry
private static class ObjectFactoryNew {

    private static final QName EVENT_QNAME = new QName(
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "Veranstaltung");

    private ObjectFactoryNew() {

    }

    /**
     * Create an instance of {@link JAXBElement }{@code <}
     * {@link Veranstaltung } {@code >}
     * 
     */
    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", name = "Veranstaltung")
    public static JAXBElement<eiv.Veranstaltung> createEvent(
            eiv.Veranstaltung value) {
        return new JAXBElement<eiv.Veranstaltung>(EVENT_QNAME,
                eiv.Veranstaltung.class, null, value);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-15" standalone="yes"?>
<xsi:Veranstaltung xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="eiv-punktemeldung.xsd"      
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<VNR>2760012007000000289</VNR>
<Meldungsart>N</Meldungsart>
<Teilnehmeranzahl>1</Teilnehmeranzahl>
<EMAIL>lukas.mustermann@mailinator.com</EMAIL>
<Teilnehmer>
    <EFN>802760010002185</EFN>
    <Punkte_Basis_JN>J</Punkte_Basis_JN>
    <Punkte_Zusatz_Lernkontrolle_JN>N</Punkte_Zusatz_Lernkontrolle_JN>
    <Punkte_Interaktivitaet_JN>N</Punkte_Interaktivitaet_JN>
    <Punkte_Referent>0</Punkte_Referent>
</Teilnehmer>
</xsi:Veranstaltung>
```

How I can I avoid "xsi:Veranstaltung" ? What do Im wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct in your case.

```
private static final QName EVENT_QNAME = new QName(
            "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance", "Veranstaltung");
```

From [**QName**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/namespace/QName.html#QName(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) documentation:

> public QName(String namespaceURI,
>        String localPart)
>   **Parameters:**
>        *namespaceURI* - Namespace URI of the QName
>        *localPart* - local part of the QName

So your root element `<Veranstaltung>` has namespace `"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` (with alias `xsi`).
If you don't want this namespace, you should create `QName` with local part only.

```
private static final QName EVENT_QNAME = new QName("Veranstaltung");
```